# data.table R lag with condition and sum values

Tags: r, data.table

I have some data like this:

```
test <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,1,5,5,5,6,7),
           time = c(0,1,4,5,6,7,9,10),
           cond = c("a","a","b","a","b","b","b","b"),
           value = c(5,3,2,4,0,3,1,2), 
           stringsAsFactors=F)

 setDT(test)[,order := order(time),id][order(id,order)]

 id time cond value order
 1  0    a    5     1
 2  1    a    3     1
 1  4    b    2     2
 5  5    a    4     1
 5  6    b    0     2
 5  7    b    3     3
 6  9    b    1     1
 7  10   b    2     1
```

I would like to return the value where the condition = "a", or sum the previous values for rows where the condition = "b" and attribute them to the previous "a" row grouped by id.  In the case of a "b" row with no preceding "a" row, the row would be dropped.  So the previous example would result in this data table.

```
id time cond value order sum
1  0    a    5     1     7
2  1    a    3     1     3
5  5    a    4     1     7
```

A function like this would work for simple situations where there is only 1 "b" row in a sequence:

```
library(zoo)
test[cond != 'b', prev := value]
test[, prev := na.locf(prev), id]
```

However I am not sure how to sum the previous values rather than just return the previous row.

Comment: Just as a note, your `[order(id, order)]` did not set the order as I imagine you wanted. You likely want to use `setorder(test, id, order)` in this case.

Comment: Yeah, zack's point can be seen in the first three rows with id = 1, 2, 1 instead of 1, 1, 2. (Maybe simply `setorder(test, id, time)` would also work.) Also you display an extra row with time = 10 that is not created above.

Comment: Also, the ```[order(id, order]``` was only placed to show order in the example not to reorder the actual object.

Comment: Added missing row to example data.

Comment: I don't understand the `time` and `sum` columns in your desired output - can you explain how you computed them?

Comment: time is just a timestamp used to create a sequence order.  For any rows where cond = a, then return the value.  For rows where cond = b, sum all preceding values until reaching a prior "a" row.  For instance, in the example, id 5 has 3 rows, so we would sum the value of all 3 rows (4+0+3=7).  Sum in this case would be 7 and we drop the b rows.

Comment: your question is ill-defined for a lot of edge cases, but here's a starting point for you (including some guesswork on what you actually want): `test[order(id, time), c(.SD[1], cond = cond[1], sum = sum(value)), by = .(id, cumsum(cond == 'a'))][cond == 'a']`